# Multi-video classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification, computer-vision

I want to build a classifier which uses multiple videos. I know video classifiers exist, but they rely on a single video.

The obvious solution is to create an ensemble classifier which uses the outputs of classifiers trained on a single video to provide multi-video classification. For example, training a MLP or XGBoost on the outputs of the pre-softmax layer.

While this is ok, I was wondering whether there are any more elegant/specialized end-to-end solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at it is like multi-modality training, where all inputs are of the same modality - a practical example is to run a DNN on each video, and then concatenate the embeddings and run the rest of the network based on it. This is similar to the solution you describe but the training is unified and is done end to end.
P.S. Another obvious solution is to concatenate the videos and feed them as a single input to a general video classifier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).